# is it possible to detect the name of properties of a NSObject

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSObject

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject 
@property bool pName1;
@property NSString *pName2;
```

I hope to detect the name(pName1,pName2..) of properties in the function

```
-(void)dosomething:(id)a
```

Is it possible? 
Welcome any comment

Comment: @ranReloaded KVC and KVO rely on you already knowing the names of an object's properties. If you want to discover those names dynamically, you need to look to the Obj-C runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of the properties for a given class using the runtime function `class_copyPropertyList()`. There's also a runtime function `property_getName()` that will give you the name for a given property. Using these two functions, you can get the names of all the properties for a given object.